# How to install xvfb on Scrapinghub for using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy, xvfb, scrapinghub

I use **Python-Selenium** in my spider (Scrapy), for using Selenium  i should install xvfb on **Scrapinghub**.

when i use `apt-get` for installing xvfb i have this error message:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)                                                                                                                                                                
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Is there any other way for installing  **xvfb** on **Scrapinghub**?

**UPDATE 1**

I read [this](https://github.com/scrapinghub/shub-image/blob/master/docs/deploy-custom-image.rst), I tried to use **docker**, I am stuck at this stage

```
shub-image init --requirements path/to/requirements.txt
```

i read this

> If you are getting an ImportError like this while running shub-image init:
>   You should make sure you have the latest version of shub installed by
>   running:
>
> $ pip install shub --upgrade

but i have always this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/shub-image", line 7, in <module>
    from shub_image.tool import cli
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/shub_image/tool.py", line 42, in <module>
    command_module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/shub_image/push.py", line 4, in <module>
    from shub.deploy import list_targets
ImportError: cannot import name list_targets
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problems ( **use selenium in scrapinghub** )

**1-** for **xvfb** in docker i use

```
RUN apt-get install -qy xvfb
```

**2-**  for creating **docker image** i used [this](https://github.com/scrapinghub/shub-image/blob/master/docs/deploy-custom-image.rst) 
 and for installing geckodriver i use this code

```
#
# Geckodriver Dockerfile
#

FROM blueimp/basedriver

# Add the Firefox release channel of the Debian Mozilla team:
RUN echo 'deb http://mozilla.debian.net/ jessie-backports firefox-release' >> \
  /etc/apt/sources.list \
  && curl -sL https://mozilla.debian.net/archive.asc | apt-key add -

# Install Firefox:
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y \
    firefox \
  # Remove obsolete files:
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf \
    /tmp/* \
    /usr/share/doc/* \
    /var/cache/* \
    /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    /var/tmp/*

# Install geckodriver:
RUN export BASE_URL=https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download \
  && export VERSION=$(curl -sL \
    https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest | \
    grep tag_name | cut -d '"' -f 4) \
  && curl -sL \
  $BASE_URL/$VERSION/geckodriver-$VERSION-linux64.tar.gz | tar -xz \
  && mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/geckodriver

USER webdriver

CMD ["geckodriver", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

from [here](https://github.com/blueimp/geckodriver/blob/master/Dockerfile)

Comment: Hi parik! I made another update to the last answer, so there are two option to solve the problem, I'm glad you could find a way before, sorry I couldn't answer sooner :/

Comment: @DamianLattenero thanks man, your answer helped me a lot, i didn't accept it because it doesn't covered all the steps of problems, thanks again

Answer (score 3):

did you try:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

Another way is to compile manually the packages, a sort of:

```
apt-get source xvfb
./configure --prefix=$HOME/myapps
make
make install
```

And the third way, is download the .deb from the source web page https://pkgs.org/download/xvfb

after download it, you can mv it to the path of the downloaded sources:

```
mv xvfb_1.16.4-1_amd64.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

then you change your directory and do:

```
sudo dpkg -i xvfb_1.16.4-1_amd64.deb
```

and that's all!

Comment: On Scrapinghub we can't use sudo, because we are not root

Comment: @parik okey, I updated the answer, hope that helps, let me know

Comment: Thanks for your answer Damian,  is it possible to put it in setup.py ?

Comment: @parik Sure, check this https://www.pydanny.com/python-dot-py-tricks.html, glad to help :)

Comment: thanks, i think that it's better to try Docker, because on scrpainghub i don't know what i put instead of ./configure --prefix=$HOME/myapps, i try docker and i wait for an answer from someone from Scrapinghub